# Key/pair default value

Tags: yii

I am trying to create a form which will have multiple fields , some fields will be filled by user and others will be dump into database as defined .

I really do not know how to work with this in term of syntax.

To be more Generic , For Example I have Post tble which have following fileds

```
            id' => 'ID',
        'post_head' => 'Heading',
        'post_desc' => 'Description',
        'post_tags' => 'Tags',
        'created_time' => 'Created Time',
        'created_date' => 'Created Date',
        'post_image' => 'Upload Image',
        'post_status' => 'Status',
        'user_id' => 'User',
        'category_id' => 'Category',
    );
```

Now I want to take input from user in the following fields only :

```
Heading
Description
Tags
```

Upload Image

Now I want to know that How can I

1. pass current time and current date in database field without user
2. input. user id from session

Answer (score 1):

In your model:

```
function beforeSave() {
    if($this->getIsNewRecord()) {
        $this->created_date = new CDbExpression('NOW()');
        $this->created_time = new CDbExpression('NOW()');
    }
    $this->user_id = Yii::app()->user->id;
    return parent::beforeSave();
}
```

Comment: I did this , But still fields are going blank to database

Comment: Show us how you save the model.

Comment: What you want to see? I did not get it

Comment: How do you save your model? Can you provide your controller action, or any other place where you `$model->save()`.

Answer (score 1):

1) If the you use database like MySQL you don't need `created_date` and `created_time`, just a `datetime` field (probably `created_time` is such), which will store both data!

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return array(
        'CTimestampBehavior' => array(
            'class' => 'zii.behaviors.CTimestampBehavior',
            'updateAttribute' => false,
            'createAttribute' => 'created_time',
        )
    );
}
```

Then for two:

```
function beforeSave() {
    if (!parent::beforeSave) {
        return false;
    }
    $this->user_id = Yii::app()->user->id; // it should be this one, but it depends on how you implemented logging!
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of

   `'created_time' => 'Created Time',

   'created_date' => 'Created Date',`

You need just one field in your database:

`create_time timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Many of php functions use timestamp, it's very easy to use it. You can read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php).
So if you insert NULL `create_time`, mysql will insert default value `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` - current time.

1. As said @Veseliq and @mashingan you need to add

   ```
   function beforeSave() {     
       $this->user_id = Yii::app()->user->id;  
      return parent::beforeSave();  
   }
   ```

   or try to add in your form view:

   ```
   echo $form->hiddenField($model, 'user_id', array('value'=>Yii::app()->user->id));
   ```

If it doesn't work, show us `var_dump(Yii::app()->user->id);`